# symfony crawler not work from this site

Tags: php, symfony, domcrawler

I want to get data from this site but symfony crawler not worked for http://www.varzesh3.com/livescore/feed and the string does not gain

```
<?php

//echo __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';


use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;


$html2 = file_get_contents('http://www.varzesh3.com/livescore/feed');

$crawler = new Crawler($html2);


$atc =  $crawler->filter('.stage-wrapper')->each(function (Crawler $nodeCrawler)
{
    var_dump($nodeCrawler->html());
    echo "a";
});
```

Comment: What did you get from `var_dump($nodeCrawler->html());`

Comment: You have to use  **CssSelector Component**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5857047/renjith-vr
I do not get anything var_dump($nodeCrawler->html());

Comment: '$crawler->filter' Did not return any value

Comment: Just read this and try. It is not good to copy paste code from there to here. - http://www.ymc.ch/de/blog/webscraping-in-php-with-guzzle-http-and-symfony-domcrawler/

Comment: If you don't get it, Let me know.

Comment: @RenjithVR  for other site its ok . but for this link not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it

get data by [Guzzle php](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) and then pass body to symfony crawler